# Difference in Count while combining querys and individual Query

Tags: mysql

While Combining Query is

```
SELECT
    stdt.`DIST_VC_DNE`,
    COUNT(Farmer_ID) AS Farmer_Cnt,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN STATUS = 'Analysed' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS Analysed_Cnt
FROM
    `tt_mao_soil_sample_dtls` tms
    INNER JOIN tt_mao_soil_farmer_dtls FAR ON FAR.`Soil_Sample_ID` = tms.`Soil_Sample_ID`
    INNER JOIN `st_com_dist` STDT ON STDT.DIST_VC_DC = tms.District_ID
WHERE
    Far.print_status IS NULL
    AND Is_active = 'Y'
    AND stl_user_id = 2222
    AND Unique_ID LIKE '2016-17%'
GROUP BY
    District_ID;
```

And Resultset Is

```
DIST_VC_DNE | Farmer_Cnt | Analysed_Cnt
----------------------------------------
 AP             24340         20177
 TS             4             0
```

While writing indivudual Query-

```
SELECT DIST_VC_DNE,COUNT(*) AS Analysed_Cnt 
FROM tt_mao_soil_sample_dtls 
WHERE `district_id`=10 AND Is_active='Y' AND stl_user_id=2222
AND Unique_ID LIKE '2016-17%';
```

And Resultset Is

```
DIST_VC_DNE | Analysed_Cnt
---------------------------
AP               13065     <===This is the correct result
```

Comment: In Join query you are comparing Soil_Sample_ID also, whats about that?.....Can you update SQLFiddle or example table data with your requirement...

Comment: In the second query, there is one more condition `district_id=10`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your joins in the first query. This is the reason its returning the wrong count value. When you have no joins in the 2nd query you get the right count value.

I'm not familiar with the data so unable to help further.